Configuring appSettings for FunctionApp & AppService via Bicep
I am migrating from ARM Templates to Bicep files.
I am using the VS Code extension to decompile ARM into Bicep.
I see a difference in handling appSettings between FunctionApp and AppService. I am wondering if there is any difference between those and if one is preferred.
FunctionApp
resource funcApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: funcAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'

resource funcApp_appSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2023-12-01' = {
  parent: funcApp
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: {
    KEY1: value1
    KEY2: value2
  }
}

AppService
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: appService_name
  location: location
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan_id
    siteConfig: {
       appSettings: [
          {
            name: KEY1
            value: value1
          }
          {
            name: KEY2
            value: value2
          } 
       ]
    }
  }
}


Both approaches are valid for functions and webapp. the difference is the schema depending on whether it is included in the site config or as a seperated resource


I see a difference in handling appSettings between FunctionApp and AppService. I am wondering if there is any difference between those and if one is preferred.

Yes, both approaches are valid when it comes to the app settings configuration of an Azure app services. The architectures are implemented differently for each individual, and you need to choose the one between those based on the requirement.
Main Difference:
For an app service, we usually define app settings under a site config{} block within the web sites resource provider. But for a function app, we use a separate resource provider called
Web/sites/config to configure the app settings. And that is also not mandatory. It is also possible to use a site_config block under a function app for simpler configurations.
Basically, the functionality of the app settings of a function app allows us to manage settings independently from the main Function App resource. (Configuration as a child resource)
But in app service, all the settings configurations will be tied within the web app as it has a frequent updates in the configuration settings.
Note: If you have a huge settings or require any pieces of modularity, the Function App approach will be more useful. For simpler configurations rather than complexed ones, the App Service approach is the one. It means, if the configuration is not required any frequent changes, the inline  siteConfig.appSettings would be suitable.
Example:
I have executed a sample bicep scripts for Function App and an App service as shown below with a detailed portal view.
param storageType string = 'Standard_LRS'
param location string = 'WestUS2'
param runtime string = 'node'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: 'xxxx'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageType
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    defaultToOAuthAuthentication: true
  }
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' = {
  name: 'xxx'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  name: 'xxxx'
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~14'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: runtime
        }
      ]
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}





This is not true. both approaches are valid for function and webapp are they are both app services.

Yes @Thomas I have mentioned that as well in the first line of my answer.

I mean it works the same for function app, you can define app settings in either ways. there is no specific case for standard web app or function app

Have you verified the above approach. @user3573101
